# Europa and Mars

Tags: riddle, knowledge, geography

Well... how do I word this...

Dear Puzzling SE: We're doomed. In two days from now, Europa and Mars will collide. They've sent a message, without themselves. They ask what word is needed.

one has a sekret,
One went insane,
one has changed,
one is an angel.

One is fading,
one wants to be with you,
one has intentions,
one has a guilty pleasure.

one is, wel, a secret,
One turned off the lights,
One is self descriptive,
one still has hope.

Now we skip a few.

Efficient people, in our minds, are rockstars.
a circus has been locked in.
others, they want to die together,
And a lucky one says that's rich.

Behold what we are showing you.
This isn't even all.

**What will happen in two days?**

Hint ONE:

> Europan alphabet is from A to I. Mars should be named Mars Junior, or a friend of Zelos, Kratos, and Bia.

Hint TWO:

> One day until the first part. There are three parts, and some meteors reappear.

Hint THREE:

> Part 2 of the takeover is over. Twenty and the big ones are coming. Quickly, prepare. Part 3 will come in 2 parts.

Comment: Is secret supposed to be spelt sekret?

Comment: Yes, all of the misspellings are important.